# Error post photos facebook

Tags: facebook, mobile, flexbuilder

I am using the GraphAPI_Mobile_1_8_1.swc to send photos in Facebook through a mobile application made ​​in Flex 4.6, but it is giving error when posting, but I can not identify, can someone help me?
down the code of how I'm doing ....

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<s: View xmlns: fx = "http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns: s = "library: / / ns.adobe.com / flex / spark" title = "PostPhotos"
creationComplete = "init (event)">
<fx:Declarations>
<! - Place non-visual elements (eg, services, value objects) here ->
</ fx: Declarations>

<fx:Script>
<! [CDATA [
com.facebook.graph.FacebookMobile import;

mx.events.FlexEvent import;
mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent import;

public var permissions: Array = ["user_photos", "user_birthday", "read_stream", "publish_stream"];

public function init (event: FlexEvent): void {
FacebookMobile.init ("my id" OnLogin);
}


protected function postPhoto(): void {
var values: Object = {message: 'mobiFace' fileName 'FILE_NAME', image: imgUser};
FacebookMobile.api ('/ me / photos', handlePhoto, values​​, 'POST');
}


protected function handlePhoto(response: Object, fail: Object): void {
imgUser.source = null;
lblStatus.Text = (response)? 'Photograph posted successfully', 'Error in posting';
}


]]>
</ fx: Script>
<s:Image id="imgUser" x="10" y="10" width="157" height="117" source="image/facebook (6).png"/>

<s:Label id="lblStatus" x="9" y="219" />
<s:Button x="10" y="147" width="157" label="Post photo" click="{postPhoto()}"/>
</ s: View>
```

I'm carrying to post any image in the Image ...
Error in posting but returns as a function handlePhoto ... and I do not know why ....

Comment: What's in your `fail` object?

Comment: failure is returning the object, but apparently the code is correct, so I do not know why is not posting

Comment: Can you post JSON serialized `fail` object? It'll probably contain real error you receive...

Answer (score 0):

I converted to the bitmapData imgUser Direct ....

```
protected function postPhoto (): void {
   var values: Object = {message: '+ Flex Mobile Post', image: imgUser.bitmapData};
   FacebookMobile.api ("/ me / photos", handlePhotovalues​​, "POST");
}
```